# Why does this need both (Eq t, Num t) as type classes?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, typeclass

So I am doing some exercised in Haskell and I thought the type of `int2nat` in

```
int2nat :: (Eq t, Num t) => t -> Nat

int2nat 0 = Zero
int2nat n = Succ (int2nat (n-1)
```

would be `int2nat :: (Num t) => t -> Nat`.

Can somebody explain why this is not the case and why the additional `Eq t` is correct instead?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please always use code instead of pictures of code in your questions, as it makes it easier for others to read and test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you matched on the numeric literal `0` in the pattern. `int2nat 0 = Zero` desugars to something like `int2nat n | n == fromInteger 0 = Zero`.